# Openpyxl to treeview passing information

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, openpyxl

I'm trying to pass some data from an excel file to a treeview in python. I can not get how to distribute every cell value to a different column. I have a treeview with three columns.

For get the data from the excel file and passing to the treeview:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from openpyxl import load_workbook

self.add_packing_tree = ttk.Treeview(self.left_area_frame_top_bottom, selectmode='extended')
self.add_packing_tree['columns'] = ('ID', 'Nro Parte', 'Cantidad')
self.add_packing_tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
self.add_packing_tree.column('#0', anchor=tk.W, minwidth=0, stretch=0, width=0)
self.add_packing_tree.column('ID', anchor=tk.W, minwidth=50, stretch=1, width=50)
self.add_packing_tree.column('Nro Parte', anchor=tk.W, minwidth=50, stretch=1, width=50)
self.add_packing_tree.column('Cantidad', minwidth=50, stretch=1, width=50)
self.add_packing_tree.heading('ID', text="ID")
self.add_packing_tree.heading('Nro Parte', text="Nro Parte")
self.add_packing_tree.heading('Cantidad', text="Cantidad")

file_location = self.filename
workbook = xl.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
self.file_route.set(self.filename)
wb = load_workbook(self.filename)
sheet = wb.active
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=0):
   for cell in row:
      self.add_packing_tree.insert('', 'end', values=(cell.value))
```

And it works great, but in the treeview all goes to the first column.

Thanks.

Comment: May I see `print(str(type(self.add_packing_tree)))`. From which `module`?

Comment: Thanks for the replay @stovfl, the prints shows `<type 'instance'>`. And what do you mean by which module?

Comment: <type 'instance'> does not help. Edit your Question and show from which `python module` you import `treeview`.

Comment: Sorry, the treeview I imported from ttk module.

Comment: It would realy help if you edit your Question and add your `import` and instantiation line of `self.add_packing_tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation » **:  [tkinter.ttk.html#item-options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#item-options)
>   values
>   The list of values associated with the item.

Change to the following:

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=0):
  self.add_packing_tree.insert('', 'end', values=[cell.value for cell in row])
```